# Jquery get DOM value for clientwidth

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, width

```js
var widthvalues = $("#spectablecontent").find(".spec-table__thead.spec-table__thead--original th p").map(function(index, element) {
  console.log(($(element)))
  console.log("clientWidth " + $(element)[0].clientWidth)
  console.log("innerWidth " + $(element)[0].innerWidth)
  var paddT = $(element).innerWidth() - $(element).width();
  console.log("paddT " + paddT)
  return $(element)[0].clientWidth
}).get();
console.log(widthvalues)
```

I have the code above and the result for line `console.log(($(element)))` is

```
b.fn.init [p]
0: p
accessKey: ""
align: ""
ariaAtomic: null
ariaAutoComplete: null
ariaBusy: null
ariaChecked: null
ariaColCount: null
ariaColIndex: null
ariaColSpan: null
ariaCurrent: null
ariaDescription: null
ariaDisabled: null
ariaExpanded: null
ariaHasPopup: null
ariaHidden: null
ariaKeyShortcuts: null
ariaLabel: null
ariaLevel: null
ariaLive: null
ariaModal: null
ariaMultiLine: null
ariaMultiSelectable: null
ariaOrientation: null
ariaPlaceholder: null
ariaPosInSet: null
ariaPressed: null
ariaReadOnly: null
ariaRelevant: null
ariaRequired: null
ariaRoleDescription: null
ariaRowCount: null
ariaRowIndex: null
ariaRowSpan: null
ariaSelected: null
ariaSetSize: null
ariaSort: null
ariaValueMax: null
ariaValueMin: null
ariaValueNow: null
ariaValueText: null
assignedSlot: null
attributeStyleMap: StylePropertyMap {size: 0}
attributes: NamedNodeMap {length: 0}
autocapitalize: ""
autofocus: false
baseURI: "XXXX"
childElementCount: 0
childNodes: NodeList [text]
children: HTMLCollection []
classList: DOMTokenList [value: ""]
className: ""
clientHeight: 46
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 0
clientWidth: 228
contentEditable: "inherit"
dataset: DOMStringMap {}
dir: ""
draggable: false
elementTiming: ""
enterKeyHint: ""
firstChild: text
firstElementChild: null
hidden: false
id: ""
innerHTML: "↵                            品番↵                            ↵                        "
innerText: "品番"
inputMode: ""
isConnected: true
isContentEditable: false
lang: ""
lastChild: text
lastElementChild: null
localName: "p"
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
nextElementSibling: null
nextSibling: text
nodeName: "P"
nodeType: 1
nodeValue: null
nonce: ""
offsetHeight: 46
offsetLeft: 0
offsetParent: th
offsetTop: 0
offsetWidth: 228
onabort: null
onanimationend: null
onanimationiteration: null
onanimationstart: null
onauxclick: null
onbeforecopy: null
onbeforecut: null
onbeforepaste: null
onbeforexrselect: null
onblur: null
oncancel: null
oncanplay: null
oncanplaythrough: null
onchange: null
onclick: null
onclose: null
oncontextmenu: null
oncopy: null
oncuechange: null
oncut: null
ondblclick: null
ondrag: null
ondragend: null
ondragenter: null
ondragleave: null
ondragover: null
ondragstart: null
ondrop: null
ondurationchange: null
onemptied: null
onended: null
onerror: null
onfocus: null
onformdata: null
onfullscreenchange: null
onfullscreenerror: null
ongotpointercapture: null
oninput: null
oninvalid: null
onkeydown: null
onkeypress: null
onkeyup: null
onload: null
onloadeddata: null
onloadedmetadata: null
onloadstart: null
onlostpointercapture: null
onmousedown: null
onmouseenter: null
onmouseleave: null
onmousemove: null
onmouseout: null
onmouseover: null
onmouseup: null
onmousewheel: null
onpaste: null
onpause: null
onplay: null
onplaying: null
onpointercancel: null
onpointerdown: null
onpointerenter: null
onpointerleave: null
onpointermove: null
onpointerout: null
onpointerover: null
onpointerrawupdate: null
onpointerup: null
onprogress: null
onratechange: null
onreset: null
onresize: null
onscroll: null
onsearch: null
onseeked: null
onseeking: null
onselect: null
onselectionchange: null
onselectstart: null
onstalled: null
onsubmit: null
onsuspend: null
ontimeupdate: null
ontoggle: null
ontransitioncancel: null
ontransitionend: null
ontransitionrun: null
ontransitionstart: null
onvolumechange: null
onwaiting: null
onwebkitanimationend: null
onwebkitanimationiteration: null
onwebkitanimationstart: null
onwebkitfullscreenchange: null
onwebkitfullscreenerror: null
onwebkittransitionend: null
onwheel: null
outerHTML: "<p>↵                            品番↵                            ↵                        </p>"
outerText: "品番"
ownerDocument: document
parentElement: th
parentNode: th
part: DOMTokenList [value: ""]
prefix: null
previousElementSibling: null
previousSibling: text
scrollHeight: 46
scrollLeft: 0
scrollTop: 0
scrollWidth: 228
shadowRoot: null
slot: ""
spellcheck: true
style: CSSStyleDeclaration {alignContent: "", alignItems: "", alignSelf: "", alignmentBaseline: "", all: "", …}
(...)
length: 1
__proto__: Object(0)
```

I want to get the value (for the first element)`clientWidth: 228` but when i do $(element)[0].clientWidth im getting `clientWidth 233` I dont understand where the change in values happens. the sample console.log is :

[image]

UPDATE:

[image]

[image]

> Goal is : To get the value of clientWidth which is `228` not `233` which is what im getting currently.

Comment: Is there a reason why you instantiate 7 jQuery objects for every element in the filtered array? And why jQuery at all if you only use it for selecting elements to then unwrap them into vanilla DOM nodes?

Comment: Also pushing to another array and return an array

Comment: nothing in particular i change those actually I just copy paste the current code i can follow the good practice later i guess i just need to make this one work first. What i dont understand is the value return by `console.log("clientWidth " + $(element)[0].clientWidth)` is different from the value in the `$(element)` when I assume i am using the same element..

Comment: for the array push dont bother about that it is from the original code I can just delete that one. @mplungjan

Comment: @Andreas i am not sure if the return value for .width() is the same with that of vanilla my just doing trial and error on this one. because I dont see why there is a difference in result when checking the resulf of `$(element)` and `$(element)[0].clientWidth`

Comment: You're not using the value for anything but a `console.log()` call, so I don't see how this is relevant for the end result in `widthvalues`

Comment: @Andreas what I want to achieve is when I do console.log the value from `$(element)[0].clientWidth` first element will match the from the array first element which is not currently base on the screen shot which is supposed to be `228` in the console.log i am getting `233` that is what confuses me.. why is that happening how can i get the value `228` based on the code above ?

Comment: Can you update your snippet to that it's runable and produces the result you're seeing.  A huge dump of `$(element)` and some (seemingly random/unrelated) console logs doesn't help us see what you're seeing.  Include your HTML in the snippet and get it so it demonstrates the issue, with just the relevant code to demonstrate the issue (then you won't get off-topic comments about your code efficiency).

Comment: Use a `,` comma in console.log (in modern browsers) rather than `+`, eg `console.log("clientWidth", $(element)[0].clientWidth)` so it doesn't coerce the value to a string (and possibly lose info in the process)

Comment: @freedomn-m i did try using comma still the value are not the same im getting different will update the question

Comment: @freedomn-m still the values are not the same

Comment: No, it won't change the *value*, just the output, eg if you do `console.log("element " + $(element))` you'll get `element [Object object]` but with a comma you'll get the the object details.  It wasn't meant as an answer, just a helper - I should have added "offtopic"

Comment: @freedomn-m i added my goal i hope it is clear now .